# Wordpress Plugin works on localhost but not on server

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I would like to know if wordpress has feature which plugins could use to define there host and block others from running them. I have a one plugin which works well on localhost but not able to work on my server. The problem is host problem i tried editing /wp-includes/network.php and change the localhost value by mine but no luck.

Comment: Never edit WordPress core files!

Comment: Which plugin is it?